# How to detect when toggle state has been changed in another component in react

Tags: reactjs, render, react-props

I am researching render props in React. I have a small test project build solely for learning. Favorite component toggles the heart from empty to full when the state of "on
" changes. Toggler component handles the state of on and changes /sets state of on with the toggle function. I'm now on FavoriteText component. What I would like this component to do is when state changes in Favorite component to say a full heart, I want the text in the FavoriteText component to reflect the change with text saying "full heart" or "empty heart". I realize this could've easily been done by including the text in Favorite, but again i am looking to acquire more knowledge on render props in React.

FavoriteText.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Toggler from "./Toggler"

function FavoriteText(props) {
    return(
        <Toggler defaultOnValue={false} render={
            (on)=>(
                <h1>{on } ? "Full Heart": "Empty Heart"}</h1>
            )
        }/>
    )
}

export default FavoriteText
```

Toggler.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class Toggler extends Component {
    state = {
        on: this.props.defaultOnValue
    }

    toggle = (e) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                on: !prevState.on
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
         <div>{this.props.render(this.state.on, this.toggle)}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Toggler
```

Favorite.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import Toggler from "./Toggler"

function Favorite(props) {
    return (
        <Toggler defaultOnValue={false} render={
            (on, toggle)=> (
                <div>
                    <h3>Click heart to favorite</h3>
                    <h1>
                        <span 
                            onClick={toggle}
                        >
                            {on ? "❤️" : "♡"}
                        </span>
                    </h1>
                </div>

        )} />
    ) 
}

export default Favorite
```

Comment: You will have to hoist the state of `Toggler` up to its parent component ('Favorite') and then pass down that state as a prop.

Comment: Toggler  is already being imported to the  Favorite and FavoriteText components

Comment: Right, but each of those uses are two separate instances of the `Toggler` component.  So my advice still stands - hoist the state of `Toggler` to its parent (`Favorite` and `FavoriteText`) and pass that down as a prop to `Toggler`.